# can't get brightness ionic cordova-plugin-brightness

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, brightness

I have problem with get brightness from cordova-plugin-brightness. 
I get undefind object. (I can set brightness but I can't get brightness)

```
         var LightControl = cordova.plugins.brightness;

            LightControl.getBrightness();
            console.log("brightness: "+LightControl.getBrightness());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation of this plugin](https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-plugin-brightness), you need to pass functions as parameters to the `getBrightness()` function.

So in that case, your code would look something like this:

```
var LightControl = cordova.plugins.brightness;

LightControl.getBrightness(function(brightness) {
  console.log("The current brightness is: " + brightness);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```